# Parsing a complexly nested XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I had been reading various tutorials but couldn't figure out to conditionally parse the following XML structure, where user inputs name of a State and then receive the name of the Capitol.

When I test it with the following code, I get no MessageBox popped up.

**C# code**

```
XDocument xd = XDocument.Load("Foo.xml");

foreach (var state in xd.Descendants("State"))
{
      Messagebox.Show(state.Attribute("Name").Value);
}
```

**Foo.xml**

```
<Main>
   <Title></Title>
   <Planet Name="Earth">
      <Continent Name="North America">
         <Country Name="USA">
            <State Name="Illinois" Capital="Springfield"></State>
            <State Name="Alabama" Capital="Montgomery"></State>
            ...
         </Country>
         <Country Name="Canada">
            <State Name="Alberta" Capital="Edmonton"></State>
            <State Name="British Columbia" Capital="Victoria"></State>  
            <State Name="Manitoba" Capital="Winnipeg"></State>
            ....
         </Country>
         <Country> ... </Country>
         <Country> ... </Country>
         <Country> ... </Country>
      </Continent>
   </Planet>
</Main>
```

Comment: are you missing a where clause in your linq?

Comment: Will you only have countries that are subdivided into states in your XML? I live in a (small) country that has no states and many address entry forms on the internet asks for my state which I cannot provide. And what do you want to return when different countries have states with the same name? I don't know if two such states exists but before The Soviet Union were split into independent countries Georgia was a state in The Soviet Union so it is possible.

Comment: @Hybridzz: I edited my test code to something simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
List<State> states = (from s in XDocument.Load(@"Foo.xml").Descendants("State")
    select new State
    {
        Name = s.Attribute("Name").Value,
        Capital = s.Attribute("Capital").Value
    }).ToList();

foreach (State state in states)
{
    //do something...
}

//Or get a specific state
var alabama = states.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name == "Alabama");
```

Answer (score 1):

I have modified your code a bit. This will return you the capitol from the state.

```
var stateCapital = from states in XDocument.Load(@"foo.xml").Descendants("State")
                    where states.Attribute("Name").Value == "Alabama"
                    select states.Attribute("Capital").Value;

Messagebox.Show(stateCapital);
```

If you need the names of all the Capitals for every state in a for loop-

```
var statesCollection = from states in XDocument.Load(@"foo.xml").Descendants("State") select states;

foreach (var state in statesCollection)
{
    Messagebox.Show(state.Attribute("Capital").Value);
}
```